# Multi environment configuration of SPA with vendors REST backend

Tags: angularjs, rest, single-page-application

I'm working on a single page application based on Angular 1.5.
The backend for the app is external vendor REST service.

Application will be run on 3 environments:

- local
- staging
- production

On each environment there is different URL to the backend:

- local => backend.local
- staging => backend.staging
- production => backend.production

On each environment i want to be able to run end2end tests by protractor, in this case backend will be mocked (Backend URL should point to dedicated MockServer instance)

E2E test mode

- local => mockserver.local
- staging => mockserver.staging
- production => mockserver.production

Additionaly it would be nice to build application only once and then just deploy on each environment and run E2E test before users can test it by hand.

What is the best way to handle configuration to achieve those requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I use a properties file on the webserver on each environment with the url. This way I can deploy 1 application on all environments.

As an alternative you can store your urls in a seperate 'applicationparam' table in the database

Comment: There is no backend i own. My app is only a client to vendors rest api. I only serve packed static content to client browser

Comment: Then a json file with the environment properties on your clientserver

Comment: So you advice me to serve json file on w webserver side by side with the SPA, and SPA should load the file on startup?

Comment: It is a suggesting as I don't see any other way to do it at this moment